# Can I hide limbs in blender?

Tags: rigging

I watch a video that shows that the animator can hide the character's limbs when they make animation.[image] I just want to ask can I do this in the blender?

[image]

Comment: hey I'm sure this isn't the legitimate way, but id just make an invisible material and apply it to those faces,

Answer (score 1):

If you separate the arms as distinct objects or meshes, you'll see a kind of seam between them and the shoulders, so it's probably not the right way to do it, and if you use a *Mask* modifier for the arms you'll see a hole in the shoulder, which is not good either.

What you could do is use 2 characters, one with arms, the other without, you give them the same action, and you switch their visibility.

Comment: The Mask modifier helps. Thank you!